collect2.exe: error: ld return 1 exit status
There is a simple script in c++ with SFML. When I try to compile it, I have somme errors with the compiler.
Note that no script-related errors are displayed in the code editor.
Script:
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}

Commands:
$ g++ -c src\main.cpp -I"C:\librairies\SFML-2.6.1\include"
$ g++ main.o -o sfml-app -L"C:\librairies\SFML-2.6.1\lib" -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

When I run the first command, I don't get any errors, everything goes well. But when I run the second one, this error appears:
C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/librairies/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-graphics.a when searching for -lsfml-graphics
[...]
C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/librairies/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-system.a when searching for -lsfml-system
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I have already try to change the directory of SFML but the problem still appears.

you have 64 bit compiler and downloaded 32 bit binaries .... i recommend just compiling SFML from source with your compiler and not downloading pre-built binaries, as C++ has an unstable ABI, and any binaries you download over the internet may not work in your project.

My advice for MinGW is to stop manually downloading binaries. Instead remove the MinGW you have and install msys2 and have it install your MinGW + binaries for you using pacman. That way you will always have the correct binaries for your compiler and have the latest compiler and everything is easier.

If your tools came from a package manager and you use the package manager to also download the libraries you can trust the libraries. Otherwise I'm with Ahmed. You have to make sure your libraries are compatible and in C++ is is very easy for them not to be. This is why you probably have two or three Visual Studio Runtime libraries installed on a Windows computer: One for every Visual Studio version used to build a tool you're using.

By the way, good on you for asking a linker question that can actually be answered. Usually they're missing too much information.

@AhmedAEK Building from source requires installing a bunch of dependencies. ...which can be conveniently installed from MSYS2, but at that point you might as well install the whole SFML.

The key bit of information in the error diagnostic is "skipping incompatible C:/librairies/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-graphics.a" This means that while you have the library, it is the built for the wrong target. If you have the right target but the wrong version, either the build won't compile (using stuff not in or has a different API in this version), won't link (for one reason or another the identifiers were mangled differently), or (the real horror because you might not be able to see it right away) are implemented differently enough that the program misbehaves.

@HolyBlackCat i just downloaded and compiled SFML using MinGW, it has no dependencies on windows, it was just a smooth cmake .. cmake --build ., the dependencies are for linux ... which has a package manager

you have downloaded incompatible binaries for SFML that won't work with your MinGW compiler, on windows you could easily compile SFML from source as it has no dependencies, compiling SFML with the same compiler that you use to build your project will avoid this issue, the steps are as follows.

download source code from SFML site
download and install CMake application
make sure both g++ and cmake are on your PATH environment variable (usually a checkbox during installation), you can verify by typing g++ --version and cmake --version in the cmd.
follow compiling cmake from source basically open the downloaded folder then open a cmd (or Mingw terminal if you are using MSYS2) in the folder that contains CMakeLists.txt and type

mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -G"MinGW Makefiles"
cmake --build .

the new binaries that are compatible with your compiler should now be in build/libs folder that you can use in your project.
